# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi^n}{2^{2n}}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

We have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi^n}{2^{2n}}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

It can be written as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\tan\left((\frac{\pi}{4})^n\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
It is in the form of $0^0$. we can write the limit as:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\dfrac{\ln\left(\tan(\frac{\pi}4)^n\right)}n}$$

By Hopital rule, the limit of exponent is equivalent to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(\frac{\pi}4)^{n}.\ln(\frac{\pi}4).\sec^2{(\frac{\pi}4)^n}.\cot(\frac{\pi}4)^n}{1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(\frac{\pi}4)^{n}.\ln(\frac{\pi}4)}{\cos{(\frac{\pi}4)^n}.\sin(\frac{\pi}4)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(\frac{\pi}4)}2\times\dfrac{(\frac{\pi}4)^{n}}{\sin(2(\frac{\pi}4)^n)}$$

But from here I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Actually I realized there's another problem, I don't think L'Hopital's applies to the limit you're trying to apply it to, it's not in an indeterminate form

Comment: The problem is that you are taking the derivative wrong. ${(\pi/4)}^n$ is an exponential term, so the power rule does not apply. It's derivative is again ${(\pi/4)}^n$ multiplied by the natural log of its base. It's that natural log which ultimately is responsible for the answer: $\pi/4$

Comment: @imranfat I fixed it!

Comment: Now it's just algebra. Some trig standard limits come in handy. The answer is $\pi/4$.

Comment: Use $\ln(\tan(x)) \sim \ln(x)$ for small $x$

Comment: Hey, sorry I was wrong before about not being in an indeterminate from, I saw the $\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)^n$ and thought "exponential growth" without realizing that it would go to zero. My apologies, I'm just hallucinating today.

Comment: @StephenDonovan No problem. thanks for mentioning my mistake on taking derivative earlier :)

Comment: can someone do this using,sandwich theorem? $$\frac{\pi}{4}<\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\tan\left((\frac{\pi}{4})^n\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}<??$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do this:

First note that $$\lim_{0<y \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan y}{y} = 1.$$

Next notice that $\frac{\pi^n}{4^n}; n=1,2,\ldots$ is an infinite sequence of positive numbers with limit $0$. Thus, putting the above together gives

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi^n}{4^n}\right)\right)× \left( \frac{4^n}{\pi^n}\right)= 1.$$

Raising both sides to the $\frac{1}{n}$-power gives the value of $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y= \sqrt[n]{\tan \left(x^n\right)}\implies \log(y)=\frac 1n \log\big[\tan \left(x^n\right)\big]$$where $x <1$.

Using just equivalents
$$\tan(x)\sim x$$
$$\tan(x^n)\sim x^n$$
$$\log\big[\tan \left(x^n\right)\big]\sim\log (x^n)=n\log(x)$$
$$\log(y)\sim \log(x) \implies y \sim x $$

For the fun, using my pocket calculator for $x=\frac \pi 6$ and $n=100$, the numbers differ by $1.10\times 10^{-59}$.

If you want to be more puristic
$$\sqrt[n]{\tan \left(x^n\right)}=x +\frac {x^{2n+1}}{3n}+\cdots$$

Comment: That 50 year old calculator? :)...can you please see if this could be done by sandwich theorem?